# How do I add more than one row with Zend_Db?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have an array with information which looks more or less like this:

```
$data[] = array('content'=>'asd');
$data[] = array('content'=>'asdf');
```

And I want to add both entries into the Database.

```
$db->insert('table', $data);
```

does not add both entries. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to use Zend_ Db_Table?

```
$data = array('content'=>'asdf');
$db->insert('table', $data);
```

works of course

Comment: The multi-insert feature request in Zend 2.0 ([ZF2-475](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-475)) has been closed as wontfix.

Answer (score 33):

I don't think Zend_Db supports insertion of multiple rows.

But if you just have two rows or a little more you can just use a loop.

```
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    $db->insert('table', $row)
}
```

---

[Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin), a former Zend Framework developer, wrote [this on Nabble some time ago](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Multiple-insert-update-bulk-tp673145p673149.html):

Rowsets are basically a collection object, so I would add methods to that class to allow rows to be added to the set.  So you should be able to do this:

```
// creates a rowset collection with zero rows
$rowset = $table->createRowset();

// creates one row with unset values 
$row = $table->createRow();

// adds one row to the rowset 
$rowset->addRow($row); 

// iterates over the set of rows, calling save() on each row
$rowset->save();
```

It makes no sense to pass an integer to createRowset() to create N empty rows.  You would just have to iterate through them to populate them with values anyway.  So you might as well write a loop to create and populate individual rows with application data, and then add them to the collection.

```
$rowset = $table->createRowset();
foreach ($appData as $tuple) 
{
    $row = $table->createRow($tuple);
    $rowset->addRow($row);
}
$rowset->save();
```

It does make sense to allow an array of arrays to be passed to createRowset(), since this would be consistent with the usage of passing a tuple to createRow().

```
$rowset = $table->createRowset($appData); // pass array of tuples
```

This would perform the same loop as the previous example above (except for the save() at the end), creating a new rowset of new rows, ready to be save()d.

There are two ways in SQL to improve the efficiency of inserting data:

1. Use a single INSERT statement with multiple rows:

   INSERT INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9);
2. Prepare an INSERT statement and execute it multiple times:

   PREPARE INSERT INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
   EXECUTE 1, 2, 3
   EXECUTE 4, 5, 6
   EXECUTE 7, 8, 9

However, supporting either of these improvements would add complexity to the Row and Rowset classes.  This is due to the internal way the current Zend_Db_Table_Row class differentiates between a row that needs to be INSERTed or UPDATEd when you call save().  This distinction is encapsulated by the Row object, so the Rowset doesn't know if the individual rows are new rows or modified copies of existing rows.  Therefore for the Rowset class to offer a multi-row save() method that uses more efficient SQL, the management of dirty data would have to be totally refactored.  The easier solution is for the Rowset to iterate over its rows, calling save() on each one.  This is better for OO encapsulation, though it doesn't help optimize SQL for inserting a rowset.

In any case, it's really rare to bulk-load many rows of data in a typical web request, when there's the greatest need for efficient SQL.  The difference in efficiency for a small number of rows is small, so it would be a noticeable improvement only if you're bulk-loading a huge number of rows.  If that's the case, you shouldn't be using INSERT anyway, you should be using MySQL's LOAD DATA statement, or equivalent feature if you use another RDBMS brand.  INSERT is not usually the most efficient choice for loading lots of data.

Regarding returning auto-generated keys, I wouldn't bother.  Notice that if you use plain SQL (in the mysql CLI for example), and you insert multiple rows in a single INSERT statement, you can only get the last generated id value, not the id values for all rows inserted.  This is SQL behavior; it's true for any language or any framework.

```
INSERT INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); -- returns only the id for the third tuple
```

If you do need the id for each row, you should write a loop and insert the rows one at a time, retrieving the generated id after each row inserted.

Comment: This is not true: $sql = "INSERT INTO beautiful (name, age)
  VALUES
  ('Helen', 24),
  ('Katrina', 21)"; works (just an example)

Comment: you're right. I still don't think zf supports it and there is no hint to it anywhere in the manual. but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 19):

You can execute any SQL syntax you want -- including multi-row `INSERT` statements -- via the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::query()` method.

But methods of the `Zend_Db_Table` and `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset` classes don't have any support for inserting multiple rows in one go.

Comment: @Elzo Valugi, there is no any `insertMultiple()` method in the manual and in the framework

Comment: "is" is present, "will" is an (possible/probable) future. maybe I should use "would". Just to clarify :)

Answer (score 13):

to insert multiple rows you can use Zend_Db

```
$stmt = $table->getAdapter()->prepare('INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)');

$stmt->execute( array($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $value5, $value6) );
```

(from Bill Karwin)

in your case we can change that to this code:

```
$data[] = array('content'=>'asd');
$data[] = array('content'=>'asdf');

$stmt = $table->getAdapter()->prepare('INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES (?), (?)');
$stmt->execute( $data );
```

to generate these '(?), (?)' dynamically, incase the data is dynamic, you can try using this snippet:

```
$values = implode(',',array_fill(0,count($data),'(?)'));
```

hope this helps

regards,
Riki Risnandar

Comment: I don't think this works? I have $list = array(); $list[] = array(':x' => 1, ':y' => 1); $stmt = $this->table->getAdapter()->prepare('INSERT INTO here (x, y) VALUES (:x, :y), (:x, :y)'); $stmt->execute($list); and it says: 'Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'. If I don't use an MD array then its ok... I don't think execute is supposed to take an MD array?

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I get error that there are too many placeholders. Trying to insert 50,000 rows.

Answer (score 3):

here is my solution:

```
public function saveRows($array) {
        $vAmount    = count($array);
        $values     = array();
        $columns    = array();

        foreach ($array as $colval) {
            foreach ($colval as $column=>$value) {
                array_push($values,$value);
                !in_array($column,$columns) ? array_push($columns,$column) : null;
            }
        }

        $cAmount    = count($columns);
        $values     = array_chunk($values, $cAmount);
        $iValues    = '';
        $iColumns   = implode("`, `", $columns);

        for($i=0; $i<$vAmount;$i++)
            $iValues.="('".implode("', '", $values[$i])."')".(($i+1)!=$vAmount ? ',' : null);

        $data="INSERT INTO `".$this->_name."` (`".$iColumns."`) VALUES ".$iValues;
        die($data);
        $this->query($data);
    }
```

Comment: You really should escape your query parameters.

Comment: I have to call execute() `$this->query($data)->execute();` and it work

Answer (score 1):

It's work.

```
 $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $db->quoteIdentifier('table') . ' (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ';
    $queryVals = array();
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        foreach($row as &$col) {
            $col = $db->quote($col);
        }
        $queryVals[] = '(' . implode(',', $row) . ')';
    }
    $stmt = $db->query($query . implode(',', $queryVals));
```

[how to build multiple insert query in zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802686/how-to-build-multiple-insert-query-in-zend-framework)

Answer (score 0):

If you do use ZF2 then solution might be like this:

```
$insert = $this->getSql()->insert();
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $relation = array(
        'column_one' => $value,
        'column_two' => $value
    );
    $insert->values($relation, Insert::VALUES_MERGE);
}

$insertRes = $this->executeInsert($insert);
```

Comment: The Insert::VALUES_MERGE flag seems to work only for merging columns / values pairs that will be inserted as a single row. The default flag (Insert::VALUES_SET) is completely overwriting the used column / value pairs, while this one appends the new pairs to the end of the previous ones (overwriting any existing column names with the new values).

Answer (score 0):

In Laminas this is not possible at this moment too.
So, if you use MySQL that supports a bulk insert, here is the way:

```
$table = 'table_name';
$arrData = [
    ['col1' => 'col1 value', 'col2' => 'col2 value'],
    ['col1' => 'col3 value', 'col2' => 'col4 value'],
];

$oPlatform  = $db->getPlatform();

$arrCols = array_keys($arrData[0]);
foreach ($arrCols as $col) {
    $arrColumns[] = $oPlatform->quoteIdentifier($col);
}

foreach ($arrData as $row) {
    $arrRowValues = [];
    foreach ($arrCols as $col) {
        $arrRowValues[] = $oPlatform->quoteValue($row[$col]);
    }

    $arrValues[] = '(' . implode(', ', $arrRowValues) . ')';
}

$sql = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES %s",
    $oPlatform->quoteIdentifier($table),
    implode(', ', $arrColumns),
    implode(', ', $arrValues)
);

$db->query($sql, Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```