# how to build multiple insert query in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add more than one row with Zend_Db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816910/how-do-i-add-more-than-one-row-with-zend-db)

i would like to build this query

```
INSERT INTO ad-page (ad_name, page_name) VALUES ('value1', 'value2'), ('value3', 'value4') , ....
```

i tried this which did not work

```
        $adpagemodel = new Admin_Model_AdPage();

        if(count($adpage)> 0)
            foreach($adpage as $page)
            {
                $newdatap[]['page_name'] = $page;
                $newdata[]['ad_name'] = $adname;            
            }
        $adpagemodel->insert($newdata);
```

and please also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802305/zend-form-checkbox-help)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is simple option. Create the query by hand ;)

like this:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $db->quoteIdentifier('table') . ' (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ';
$queryVals = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    foreach($row as &$col) {
        $col = $db->quote($col);
    }
    $queryVals[] = '(' . implode(',', $row) . ')';
}
$stmt = $db->query($query . implode(',', $queryVals));
```

Answer (score 2):

Not all databases support this. So, there is no universal answer.
But if you would tell what's you DB, we might suggest some trick... :-)

Comment: mysql supports this, but the problem is i don't know how to create this statement through dbmodel, instead i have to iterate through loop and insert multiple values