# bulk insert in zend framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add more than one row with Zend_Db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816910/how-do-i-add-more-than-one-row-with-zend-db)

everyone,

I need to have a bulk insert in zend framework. For normal sql I have the below query, I want to do the same in zend framework.

```
INSERT INTO `dbname`.'tablename` (`id`, `user_id`, `screen_name`, `screen_name_server`) VALUES (NULL, '15', 'test', 'test'), (NULL, '15', 'test', 'test');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to do this, as Marcin states.

If you'd like to do some messing around with the Zend Framework you'd could try to alter the 
insert.

You could try to make it so that the insert method can take an array of arrays for the data. Then you could use the arrays of data to build the bulk insert.

For example,

```
$data1 = array( ); //data for first insert

$data2 = array( ); //data for 2nd insert

//a zend_db_table object

$dbTable->insert( array( $data1, $data, ) );
```

You would have to edit the insert method a bit to detect multiple data inserts and then build the insert accordingly. Unfortunately I haven't looked into how the code is built or I would just put it up here for you to use.

Comment: +1 for the approach. I've actually done this to generate a single query to insert all rows at once. In my testing it was about 10 times faster than iterating over the data and executing a query for each tuple.

Comment: Oog genius Man .. you save my time :)

Comment: @Hameed Thanks but I haven't implemented this myself so I can't take credit for actually doing it.

Answer (score 5):

There is no insert method in zend_db that would insert multiple rows. What you can do though, is to use `query` method of `Zend_Db_Adapter` and put there your own insert sql.